# Defect in Engineering Product

Tags: probability

I have an assignment Problem but I am unable to determine the answer to the following question
Consider a rare defect with a certain type engineered wood product. During production there is a small chance (0.95%) that any one product comes out defect. If a product is defect then there is a 90% chance that the defect will be detected in a special-purpose test that all products are subjected to.  However, if a product does not have the defect then there is still a 5% chance that the test will categorize it as a defect product. How many consecutive “positive tests” do you need to see before there is a 90% chance that there is a defect?

I am assuming the probability of Defect is P(D)=0.0095. then P(ST/D)= 0.9 and P(ST/D')=.005.I am unable to find how to proceed further to determine the consecutive Positive tests. An insight here form the community Members would be Helpful.

- D- Defect in wood Product
- ST- Standard device used for testing
- D'- No defect in wood Product

I can determine the P(D')= 1-P(D)= 0.9905. However to Determine the P(ST) at P(D)=0.9 can I use the Bayes Theorem . I just need a little help to note down if these are the right steps I need to follow

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a single positive test you get

$$\mathbb{P}[\text{Defective}|\text{Detected as Defective}]=\frac{0.9\times0.095}{0.9\times0.095+0.05\times0.905}\approx65.39\%$$

If you have more than one (independent)consecutive positive tests, your conditional probability will become

$$\frac{0.9^k\times0.095}{0.9^k\times0.095+0.05^k\times0.905}$$

thus with $k=2$ you have a PPV of more than 97%

---

The above solution considers $P(D)=9.5\%$ instead of 0.95% (my fault). Using the correct data you get

$$\frac{0.9^k\times0.0095}{0.9^k\times0.0095+0.05^k\times0.9905}\geq 0.90$$

$k=1 \rightarrow p=14.7\%$

$k=2 \rightarrow p=75.7\%$

$k=3 \rightarrow p=98.2\%$

thus the answer is $k=3$

Comment: thanks for your reply. So we are assuming the events to be statistically independent and applying Conditional Probability right?. If we are using Conditional Probability then the Denominator should be of event Detected as Defective right?. Why are we adding the two Probability scenario in Denominator?. Just wanted to know the basic Idea

Comment: @suzdeex8197 : what I did it is exactly the application of Bayes' Theorem. The denominator is the probability to detect an object as defective. This can happen in 2 situations, when the object is actually defective, with a probability of 90% and when it is not defective, with a lower probability of 5%

Comment: thanks for clarifying. It was really Helpful!!.

Comment: I have a doubt in the denominator value suppose Probability of indicator showing defect is represented as P(I) then P(I)=P(I/D)*P(D)+P(I/D')*P(D'). And the P(D')=1-P(D)=1-0.0095=0.9905. However you have mentioned it as 0.905. Am I missing something here?.

Comment: @suzdeex81: sorry I solved the exercise with $P(D)=9.5\%$ and not 0.95%. Change data accordingly, the procedure does not change

Comment: I did took P(D) as 0.0095 and have followed the same Principle to calculate the value of K. so for Value of 3,  the P(Defective/Detected as Defective) sums up to 98.3 Percent, which is greater than 90 Percent . I am hoping that might be the right answer ??.

Comment: @suzdeex8197 : yes correct. I amended my solution.